# Project and Structure navigation splitting in PhpStorm 7/8/9

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Anyone know how to make project and structure navigation set in splitting mode?

See images ( I was able doing this, but don't know how )

[image: project and structure navigation]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step :

1. Preferences
2. Appearance & Behaviour
3. Appearance then untick *side-by-side layout on the left* at Window options
4. Project tab move to the left side and make sure untick *split-mode*
5. Structure tab move to the left side and make sure tick *split-mode*

Comment: thank you :) #3 is very important otherwise both tabs appear side by side instead of stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Sadly this is no longer true - none of the tool windows have a split mode option, at least in 2020.2.

Comment: I will check later on

Comment: Comment from Synchro should be accepted answer now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62309949/3673404 should be

Answer (score 20):

This took me a really long time to figure out.

For you to set this up, you need to

**First:** make sure each Tool Window is set to "Pinned Mode" and "Docked Mode" (*you can do this by right clicking on the Project/Structure tab*)

**Second:** the Tool Window you want on top should have the "Split Mode" NOT checked

**Third:** the Tool Window you want at the bottom should have the "Split Mode" checked

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just grab your "Structure" tool window button (the one on the left side, that has "7" in the title) and drag it to the bottom part of the same side.

Alternatively just right click on tool window button or title bar and choose "Split Mode" -- it will move it to the opposite part of the same side (e.g. will move from Left Top to Left Bottom -- just as per your image).

[Official manual page](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html?search=manipulating#d683881e250).

Comment: Does not work as wanted ;( Unable to resize bottom pane either Project or structure pane

Comment: @Frank You must be doing something wrong then (or your tool windows/interface settings). It's perfectly resizeable -- if I place one on top and one on bottom of the same side and then open both at the same time .. they can be resized in height with no issues. Please show screenshot of what you have got there (full window, if possible).

Comment: This is how I did [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6YY2NJhr6aeOVNpTUhrckR5WkU)

Comment: @Frank On your video, at around 0:08 when you right click on Project window tool button, just untick "Split Mode". If it's not active (not ticked), the window will be shown on top part of the left side, it active (ticket) -- on the bottom part. The issue that I see right now is that you have ALL of the tool windows have it ticket hence all of them are in the bottom part. Alternatively -- just click and hold on desired window tool button and drag&drop it to the top of the same side.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2019.1, PHPStorm tool windows no longer behave the way the other answers say, that is, there is no explicit "split mode". Instead, it uses the location of the tab; you can no longer split tool windows if they are in the same tab group, but you *can* display two tool panes by putting them in different groups. So if you're looking for the standard projects half-pane at the top, and structure at the bottom, put structure in the top left group, and structure in the bottom left, and then enable them both - and the view will split.

To reiterate – if you have both project and structure in top left, there is no way to split them; you must move the tab.

Comment: This should be here in bold: **To reiterate – if you have both project and structure in top left, there is no way to split them; you must move the tab.**

Answer (score 0):

To whom the other answers did not work:

At first go to **Windows** menu then click **Restore Default Layout**

Then go to **View** => **Tool Windows** => **Project**

Then go to **View** => **Tool Windows** => **Structure**